# How to select only rows from Pandas DataFrame with 3 characters in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, string, character

I have Pandas DataFrame like below, col1 is STRING data type:

```
col1
-----
"123"
"1111"
"287777"
NaN
"222"
```

And I need to select only these rows where string in "col1" has 3 characters, so as a result i need something like below:

```
col1:
-----
"123"
"222"
```

How can I do that in Python Pandas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [pandas.Series.str.len](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.len.html) function for this task:

```
df[df['col1'].str.len() == 3]
```

Output:

```
    col1
0   123
4   222
```